# Notebook restarts when making predictions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, regression, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

My regression model is already trained, and saved using joblib, and when I load it in order to get y_predicted eventually the notebook restarts and I don't see any error on CloudWatch.

When I run:

```
y_predicted = model.predict(x_test)
```

Here is what I get on CloudWatch:

```
[I 17:43:34.145 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports

2022-07-03T19:43:34.310+02:00


kernel 97adefc6-bb3a-469c-8c4a-91681e6eb64a restarted
kernel 97adefc6-bb3a-469c-8c4a-91681e6eb64a restarted

2022-07-03T19:43:34.310+02:00   kernel 97adefc6-bb3a-469c-8c4a-91681e6eb64a restarted

2022-07-03T19:43:34.310+02:00   kernel 97adefc6-bb3a-469c-8c4a-91681e6eb64a restarted

2022-07-03T19:43:34.310+02:00   kernel 97adefc6-bb3a-469c-8c4a-91681e6eb64a restarted

2022-07-03T19:43:34.310+02:00   kernel 97adefc6-bb3a-469c-8c4a-91681e6eb64a restarted

2022-07-03T19:43:34.310+02:00   kernel 97adefc6-bb3a-469c-8c4a-91681e6eb64a restarted

2022-07-03T19:43:38.343+02:00   kernel 97adefc6-bb3a-469c-8c4a-91681e6eb64a restarted
```

Edit: I even took a smaller part of `y_test` to see if it works, but just restarts the notebook faster than using the entire y_test, I think it is about having too many unique values on 1 feature (about 7k) and I applied one hot encoding.

Comment: Possibly crashing due to out of memory errors. Try deleting variables in scope that you don't need, or move to a higher performance instance.

Comment: Hello, I increased my Volume Size to 10000GB EBS, current instance type is ml.m5.12xlarge which allows me to train my model, not sure if the fact that I am saving my model inside the notebook instance using Pickle might have something to do with this issue. In theory it should not be an issue, model's size is 51 Gb.

Comment: +1 to OOM errors. Are you able to delete all in memory variables and just load the model and predict? The instance memory for the instance you specified is only 192 GB.

Comment: I increased the volume size ,and also changed my encoding approach, one hot encoding was taking a lot of memory and it nos a good approach for the high amount of unique values.